# Is there a pythonic way to create various DataFrames iterating over a grouped DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, group-by

I am trying to do a for loop to iterate over a column in my merged DataFrame. The column holds 52 different provinces from Spain of which I need a different DataFrame for each. I have tried to use .groupby but it doesn't work.

My final try was making a while loop and a for inside:

- There are 52 provinces, so the counter goes from 52 to 0
- As the counter goes by, the merged DataFrame has to extract the Province referring to the number within the count and save it to a specific DataFrame with the name of the Province

```
# Making a while-loop for iterating over the provinces
counter = (len(merged.Provincia.sort_values(ascending=False).unique())+1)
while counter <= (len(merged.Provincia.sort_values(ascending=False).unique())+1):
    for x in merged.Provincia.sort_values(ascending=False).unique():
        counter = pd.DataFrame(merged[merged['Provincia'] == x])
    counter -= 1
    if counter == -1:
        break
    #print (counter)
print('\n','The Loop has ended') 

print(merged.head())
index      Comunidad Provincia     Date     Alquiler      Venta
0   3120    Galicia  A Coruña   2006-01-01    5.68      1477.19 
1   3900    Galicia  A Coruña   2006-02-01    5.68      1477.19 
2   6136    Galicia  A Coruña   2006-03-01    5.68      1477.19 
3   676     Galicia  A Coruña   2006-04-01    5.68      1477.19 
4   6968    Galicia  A Coruña   2006-05-01    5.68      1477.19
```

So, the DataFrame holds data for all Spanish Provinces (in example, there are 52 different names for the provinces), I would like to make a loop to save each province into a new dataframe with the name of said province:
For example for Madrid, it would be:

```
Madrid = pd.DataFrame(merged[merged['Provincia'] == 'Madrid'])
```

I can do this by assigning it to the 52 different provinces within the datafram, but I would like to make it wihint a loop for easier manipulation

If anyone has a better idea on how to this, all are welcome :)

Comment: What is your question exactly? And what is your expected output?

Comment: Post sample input and sample output.